# Simple elif statement wont work because of 'expression expected'?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am very new to coding and just getting the jist of basic code.
I have done an if statement before but haven't come across this issue, could anyone help?

My code:

```
print("Hello User")
myName = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello" + myName)

myAge = input("What is your age?")

if input < 17:
    print("Not quite an adult!")
elif:
    print("So you're an adult!")
```

https://gyazo.com/15eef7751886747f4ce572641b9398fc

Comment: What you want is "else". Elif needs another expression after it, that's why you get an exception! And please don't include screenshots but your code directly.

Answer (score 7):

You need `else:`.

`elif` means `else if` and needs expression.

```
if expression:
    pass
elif expression:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the 'elif' to 'else'. And there you go!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> print("Hello User")
> myName = input("What is your name?")
> print("Hello" + myName)
>
> myAge = int(input("What is your age?"))
>
> if myAge < 17:
>     print("Not quite an adult!")
> elif myAge >17:
>     print("So you're an adult!")
> ```

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'>>must castingtype into int for input>>>so when use elif he Suppose you complete the condition

Comment: Your explanation belongs in the answer, not down here in a comment.